# IDENT_CURRENT return null in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, null, return

I used

> select IDENT_CURRENT('Corp') as ID;

in sql server, it returns a **value**. 
but it when i used this code in my PHP, it gave return **null**. 
whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you post the PHP code too?

Comment: function get_lastinsertCorp()
 {
  $query = $this->db->query("select IDENT_CURRENT('Corp') as ID");
  return $query->result();
 }

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct database? What authentication are you using? `IDENT_CURRENT` will return `NULL` if the user does not have the right permissions. For what it is worth, `IDENT_CURRENT` is quite an unusual thing to need to call from PHP, it is a bit of a code smell.

Comment: Is there any query that can help me to get the last insert value?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "IDENT_CURRENT" in mysql.
You can use :

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID('Corp');
```

But `LAST_INSERT_ID()` not in all cases true, so better use:

```
SELECT MAX('id') FROM Corp;
```

(id : unique identifier)

Comment: im using sqlsrv driver for my db. is it matter?